# find the location of the cmd.exe file

Tags: c++, windows, shell, visual-c++

I have built a c++ program that depends on "cmd.exe" to execute some of the tasks.
For now I and for test purposes the path to that file is "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe". 
My question is there any c++ API that returns the path of that file knowing that my program must work on win32 and on win64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter path is available in the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable which can be read with [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I can either use GetEnvironmentVariable or GetEnvironmentVariable.

Comment: Or getenv sorry I mistyped it in my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

`GetSystemDirectory` is one option. For a 32-bit app, it will return the 32-bit system directory. For an x64 app, it will return the 64-bit native system directory.

You can also use `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx` with `cmd.exe` and it should find it without the path unless you are specifically concerned about someone manipulating the search path and getting the wrong `cmd.exe`.

If you are launching a `.cmd` file, then you can just do it with `ShellExecuteEx` with the `open` verb. Generally for a Windows desktop app, use of `ShellExecuteEx` is recommended for launching other programs. For example, here's some code that will launch the command prompt running the `test.cmd` script and wait for the result:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shell32.lib")

void main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW info = {};
    info.cbSize = sizeof( info );
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    info.lpFile = L"test.cmd";
    info.lpParameters = nullptr; // Command-line parameters
    info.lpDirectory = nullptr; // Working directory to set
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    if( !ShellExecuteExW( &info ) )
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Wait for process to finish.
        WaitForSingleObject( info.hProcess, INFINITE );

        // Return exit code from process
        DWORD exitcode;
        GetExitCodeProcess( info.hProcess, &exitcode );

        CloseHandle( info.hProcess );

        printf("Finished with exit code %u\n", exitcode);
    }
}
```

You can also use:

```
info.lpFile = L"cmd.exe";
info.lpParameters = L"/c test.cmd";
```

> The primary reason to use `ShellExecuteEx` instead of `CreateProcess` is that `ShellExecuteEx` can handle admin elevation requests for exes with the proper [manifest elements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/). `CreateProcess` would fail if the target EXE requires higher privileges than your current process.

Comment: I am using CreateProcess, but CreateProcess failed to find the correct path, on my computer the command is executed only when I specify the full path to "cmd.exe".

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet but the main problem to me was only how to find the folder where lives "cmd.exe"

Comment: If the above doesn't work, then there's something wrong with your system.

Comment: Thanks @chuck walbourn my question was very specific : how to find where lives "cmd.exe".

Comment: Then ``COMSPEC`` via ``GetEnvironmentVariableW`` is your answer.